# Why am I getting org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JRuntimeException?

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

- I'm testing the POI asset (writting data into Excell sheet).
- I want to write X rows into xlsx file every time.
- I can write the first X rows, But when I'm trying to write another X rows I'm getting exception -

  org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JRuntimeException: Fail to save: an error occurs while saving the package : The part /docProps/app.xml fail to be saved in the stream with marshaller org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.DefaultMarshaller@6825c828

.

```
public class ExcellTest
{
    XSSFWorkbook workbook;
    XSSFSheet sheet;
    int rowNum = 0;
    String excellFileName = "";
    FileOutputStream fileOut;
    
    public ExcellTest(String excellFileName) {
        createExcellSheet("test");
        this.excellFileName = excellFileName;
    }
            
    public void createExcellSheet(String sheetName) {
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        sheet =  workbook.createSheet(sheetName);
    }
    
    public void addData() {
        Row rowMsg = sheet.createRow((short)rowNum);
        rowNum++;
        
        Cell cell;        
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            cell = rowMsg.createCell(i);
            cell.setCellValue(rowNum);               
        }
    }
    
    public void createExcellFile() {
        try {
            fileOut =  new FileOutputStream(new File (excellFileName));//, true);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.print("Cant write workbook into file: " + excellFileName);
        }
    }
    
    public void writeExcellSheet() {
        // write workbook into file
        try {        
            workbook.write(fileOut);                        
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           System.out.print("Cant create file: " + excellFileName);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.print("Cant write workbook into file: " + excellFileName);
        }
    }
    
    public void closeFile() {      
        try {
            fileOut.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
      ExcellTest excellTest = new ExcellTest("C:\\TestJavaBinary\\1.xlsx");
      excellTest.createExcellFile();
        
      // write 2 rows
      excellTest.addData();
      excellTest.addData();        
      excellTest.writeExcellSheet();
      
      // write 2 additional rows
      excellTest.addData();
      excellTest.addData();
        
      // THE NEXT LINE WILL THROW EXCEPTION 
      excellTest.writeExcellSheet();
      excellTest.closeFile();
}
```

I can't write rows into `xlsx` file just once, because the second attempt throws exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JRuntimeException: Fail to save: an error occurs while saving the package : The part /docProps/app.xml fail to be saved in the stream with marshaller org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.DefaultMarshaller@6825c828
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.saveImpl(ZipPackage.java:503)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.save(OPCPackage.java:1425)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.write(POIXMLDocument.java:201)
    at mainPkg.ExcellTest.writeExcellSheet(ExcellTest.java:58)
    at mainPkg.Main.main(Main.java:23)
Caused by: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JException: The part /docProps/app.xml fail to be saved in the stream with marshaller org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.DefaultMarshaller@6825c828
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.saveImpl(ZipPackage.java:494)
```

Comment: What version of Apache POI is this with? And if it isn't the latest, what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: I'm using poi-3.11 (from 21/12/2014)

Comment: Can you create a small, self-contained junit unit test which shows the problem?

Comment: @user3668129 have you got any solution?, because i'm have same problem.

Comment: no, it was long time ago, and I changed my code to support csv (instead of xlsx)